# How can I add a pulsating animation to my menu button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a pulsating animation to my menu button (something like this:
[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_RXm5NyBo0)
I tried to copy the exact code that is used in this video, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

I know the Icons don't work in my snippets, but I didn't find a way to add them but the page is hosted on this link: [Hosted Site](http://dzz-touch-table.epizy.com/)

```css
.finger{
  background: white;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top: 300px;
  position: relative;
}



.menu-button {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: pulse 2s linear ininite;

}


.menu-button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -160px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: green;
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;


}



#menu:not(:target)>a:first-of-type,
#menu:target>a:last-of-type {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}


@keyframes pulse{
    0%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 0 rgba(fff,fff,ff,.7);
    }
    40%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 50px rgba(fff,fff,ff,.7);
    }
    80%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 50px rgba(fff,fff,ff,.7);
    }
    100%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 0 rgba(fff,fff,ff,.7);
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Touch table</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#005098">
</head>

<body bgcolor= "black">
<div class="container">
     <ul id="menu" >



<!--Finger Icon-->
            <a class="menu-button icon-plus" href="#menu" title="Show navigation">  <img src="img/finger.png" width="250px"></a>
            <a class="menu-button icon-minus" href="#0" title="Hide navigation"><img src="img/finger.png" width="250px"></a>

        </ul>


    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also your HTML is *invalid*. `ul` can only have `li` as direct children.

Comment: Ok I reduced it to the relevant parts

Comment: It's just the relevant code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-shadow` is invalid. it takes the following values. Only 4 values and a color.

> `box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [optional spread radius] [color];`

Also rgba colors don't work with Hex codes, it only accepts numbers which is a color range (0 - 255) for each red/green/blue schema.

Here is a correct css for your `keyframes`

```
@keyframes pulse{
    0%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    }
    40%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    }
    80%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    }
    100%
    {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    }
}
```